# How do you auto-fill a Ransack search form with details from the previous search?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, session, ruby-on-rails-4, parameters, ransack

I have several filters that a user may apply to a search:

[image]

When the user checks a language and clicks filter, the a POST request is made to my search action:

```
def search
  index
  render :index
end
```

Which uses my index action:

```
def index
  @q = Listing.search(search_params)
  @listings = @q.result(distinct: true).page(params[:page])
end
```

`@q` is set by the [Ransack Gem](https://github.com/activerecord-hackery/ransack) and is equal to the parameters submitted by the form:

```
q   {"languages_id_eq_any":["1"]} #this would be the param if 'French' was selected
```

To display matching objects (in my case, objects of the class `Listing`).

When the page is refreshed, the search results are appropriately filtered but my search form is all unchecked.

If the user filters by `English`, I would like the `English` language option to be checked after the search results are shown (so the user remembers which filter they used).

**How would I do this?**

I know I can "check" the checkbox by changing the form code from (see further below for full form code):

```
= check_box_tag('q[languages_id_eq_any][]', language.id )
```

to

```
= check_box_tag('q[languages_id_eq_any][]', language.id, checked: true )
```

But I'm not sure how to get the search parameter information available here - or if this is the most efficient direction to be going (manually setting each value throughout the form).

---

Here is the code for the form:

```
= simple_form_for @q, url: search_listings_path,
        html: { method: :post } do |f|
  - Language.all.each do |language|
    = check_box_tag('q[languages_id_eq_any][]', language.id )
    = language.name
  = f.button :submit, 'Filter'
```

---

**Update after Toolz' answer below:**

It's still not perfect (two helpers in one rather than one all-inclusive helper, but I extracted some of the long line into a helper:

```
def filtered_checkbox_value_by_index(name, index)
  symbol = "#{name}_id_eq_any".to_sym
  unless params[:q].nil? || params[:q][symbol].nil?
    params[:q][symbol].include?((index+1).to_s)
  end
end
```

So my checkbox code becomes:

```
- Language.all.each_with_index do |language, index|
  = check_box_tag('q[languages_id_eq_any][]', language.id, filtered_checkbox_value_by_index('languages', index))
  = language.name 
  = f.button :submit, 'Filter'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change

```
- Language.all.each do |language|
  = check_box_tag('q[languages_id_eq_any][]', language.id )
```

to

```
- Language.all.each_with_index do |language, index|
  = check_box_tag('q[languages_id_eq_any][]', language.id, params[:q][:languages_id_eq_any].include?((index+1).to_s))
```